STM32 ARM GCC Toolchain CMake target_compile_features no known features for CXX compiler
Our project is using STM32 GCC ARM Toolchain, using STM32 CMake toolchain file (gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake) which sets the CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID to GNU.
When lines like this are encountered target_compile_features(my_lib PUBLIC cxx_std_11) it complains that ...
target_compile_features no known features for CXX compiler

"GNU"

version 11.3.1.

I first noticed this when trying to pull in Boost with their CMake files, which use the same target_compile_feature checks.
The CMake project does configure for Linux GCC. My CMake version is 3.30.2.
Edits

None of the solutions from the similar question address the issue described here.


"... which sets the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to GNU" - Those variables should be set to the path of compilers, or, if a directory with compilers is listed in PATH environment variable, to the name of the compilers files (gcc and g++ correspondingly). Setting these variables to literal GNU has no sense. The error message effectively tells you that CMake has failed to configure a C++ compiler.

Apologies for my typo above. As you point out, those variables should point to the compiler path and do. I was referring to CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID. Edited above.

Please, add your toolchain to the question post. The way how you describe the toolchain contradicts to the error message (where "GNU" refers to a compiler, not to a compiler ID).

Removing CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED being set to TRUE (removing those options altogether) from our toolchain file fixed the errors above. I'm not sure if our project added those options or if they were form STM32 CubeMX generated files. Those options are listed as deprecated in CMake docs.
